# Facebook login in fragment in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-fragments, facebook-login

I'm trying to login Facebook using custom interface it worked fine in Activity class. same thing i have to do in Fragment too. but Callback is not executing. is it not possible to add CallbackResult in Fragment's OnActivityResult ??

Comment: just add this to work in fragment fbLoginButton.setFragment(this);

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes it's Posssible to implement facebook login in fragment, the only thing you need to do is call OnActivityResult in your host activity like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_host_fragment_in_activity);
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

and then call onActivityResult again in yout fragment.

Comment: The problem with this method is that the onActivityResult is not working by using Navigation components, I've tried for hours to find the correct answer but still not getting any, the fragment will get you the hoster fragment instead of the called one.

Comment: @KhalodaRK84   try this in  Navigation components LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, listOf("public_profile", "email"))

Answer (score 27):

You just need to add this code in your Activity onActivityResult.

```
for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            //System.out.println("@#@");
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

Then your fragment onActivityResult will surely gonna work.

```
   @Override
        public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {


            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

Comment: For me the accepted answer from Gujarat Santana didn't work, but this one did. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

You just need to add one line inside fragment

```
fbLoginButton.setFragment(this);
```

You will get the control in

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code snippet:

```
class LoginFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentLoginBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var callBackManager: CallbackManager
    private val TAG = "LoginFragment"

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentLoginBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        callBackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
        binding.loginButton.setPermissions(listOf("email, public_profile"))
        binding.loginButton.setFragment(this)
        binding.loginButton.registerCallback(callBackManager,
            object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult?> {
                override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult?) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: ${loginResult?.accessToken?.userId}")
                }

                override fun onCancel() {
                    // App code
                }

                override fun onError(exception: FacebookException) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onError: $exception")
                }
            })

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        callBackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize CallbackManager in your activity

Declare variable

```
lateinit var callbackManager: CallbackManager
```

create it in Oncreate

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
 
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
}
```

in your onActivityResult method, call callbackManager.onActivityResult to pass the login results to the LoginManager via callbackManager

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

In yout fragment no need to call onActivityResult again just do this

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

  lateinit var callbackManager: CallbackManager

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
   
        callbackManager = (activity as MainActivity).callbackManager

        LoginManager.getInstance()
        .registerCallback(callbackManager,
            object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult?> {
                override fun onSuccess(result: LoginResult?) {

                }

                override fun onCancel() {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Login Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

                override fun onError(error: FacebookException) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            })

  }

}
```