# Xamarin Android MvvmCross MvxFragment does not call OnActivityResult

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

So I have this code:

```
[MvxFragmentPresentation(typeof(MainViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame, false)]
internal class FacebookLoginView : BaseFragment<FacebookLoginViewModel>, IFacebookCallback
{
    protected override int FragmentId => Resource.Layout.FacebookLoginView;
    private ICallbackManager _callbackManager;
    private LoginButton _loginButton;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        ParentActivity.SupportActionBar.Title = "Login";

        var accessToken = AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken;

        if (accessToken != null)
        {
            (ViewModel).FinishLogin(accessToken.Token, long.Parse(accessToken.UserId)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
        else
        {
            _loginButton = view.FindViewById<LoginButton>(Resource.Id.loginButton1);
            _loginButton.SetReadPermissions(new string[] { "user_friends", "email", "pages_show_list" });
            _callbackManager = CallbackManagerFactory.Create();
            _loginButton.RegisterCallback(_callbackManager, this);
        }

        return view;
    }

    public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        _callbackManager.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void OnCancel()
    {
        //Does nothing, just closes facebook login screen
    }

    public void OnError(FacebookException error)
    {
        //For now does nothing
    }

    public void OnSuccess(Object result)
    {
        var loginResult = result as LoginResult;
        (ViewModel).FinishLogin(loginResult.AccessToken.Token, long.Parse(loginResult.AccessToken.UserId)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

It's just a simple facebook login. The thing is, when I click login button, facebook screen pops up and then I enter my username and password and click login. after that facebook login screen closes and nothing happens.

I put breakpoints on `OnActivityResult`, `OnCancel`, `OnError` and on `OnSuccess` methods and neither of them are called.

The thing is I am trying to update my xamarin android app to fragments and I'm new to it. When `FacebookLoginView` inherited `MvxActivity` everything worked fine, I assumed that it should work the same on fragments.

Could please someone explain me what I am missing?

**UPDATE 1**
This is not a duplicate of another question. I tried doing, like @cheesebaron's link answer offered, but it didn't worked... In my MainView I added :

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    var fragment = FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("facebook_fragment");
    fragment.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

In order for it to work, in my FacebookLoginView I had to override OnStart method, to add fragment:

```
public override void OnStart()
{
    base.OnStart();

    if (FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("facebook_fragment") == null)
    {
        var transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        transaction.Add(this, "facebook_fragment");
        transaction.Commit();
    }    
}
```

Now when I try to login I get an reference null exception in MainView when app tries to find fragment by tag and it's always null. So the problem is still there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook login in fragment in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736301/facebook-login-in-fragment-in-android)

Comment: @Cheesebaron no it's not... I updated my question